# In Django i18n, the locale paths doesn't work

Tags: django, internationalization, locale

I want to make a django.po in the root of the project( contains all model and templates )
in my `settings.py` file.

`LOCAL_PATHS = ('/path/to/project/locale/', )`

but it doesn't work. . After makemessages and compilemessages,the `po/mo` file is generated successfully,but nothing happens when I change the language settings(The modeltranslation works well). So I think maybe the locale directory cannot be recognized in the project root .
Here is my project structure:

```
project
  -app/
  -app/
  -project/
      -settings.py
      -urls.py
  -templates/
  -static/
  -locale/
```

then i put the locale directory under an app directory and use the `makemessages/compilemessages` tool,
it works. But it only contains the translation which marked in this app, which means I can't make the translations that marked in templates or other apps.

Is there any better solution for this situation?

Comment: According to the docs you should be able to do that. Under local do you have the ```<locale_code>/LC_MESSAGES``` directories?

Comment: yes of course . when I do `django-admin.py makemessages -l zh_CN`,it will generate **<locale_code>/LC_MESSAGES/** directories auto.@schillingt

Comment: Did you try to change `LOCAL_PATHS` to `LOCALE_PATHS`? I think you have a typo. Experiencing the same problem tho

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here how I implemented:

I kept locale folder like this in my project:

```
-Project  #*main Project directory
  -apps
  -apps
  -templates
  -project
     -settings.py
  -locale              #outside project folder but within main Project
     -ru_RU
       -LC_MESSAGES
          -django.po
```

Now I gave the locale path in settings.py like:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

 LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../locale'),

)
```

Language choices:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', 'English'),
    ('ru_RU', 'Russian'),
)


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us' 'ru_RU'
```

Finally added the middleware:

```
django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware
```

Hopefully it will help. I wrote about it in details at my blog: http://ruddra.com/2015/09/17/django-translation-using-po-file/ .

Comment: where do you put your app and template directories? Can you show me your main project structure? (app/,locale/,project/, settings/, tempates/ ..)

Comment: Sure, I have edited my answer with my project structure.

Comment: which django version do you use? I have the same structure as you . But it still doesn't work. it seems the locale_path parameter doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it on django 1.6.1 . Did you add the middleware? coz without it, localization won't work(it didn't work for me atleast) :)

Comment: yes I have add it. if I put my locale direcotory in app's directory, it works well. That's so so so weired.

Comment: I won't  say its weird,  coz after all its all logically built (django/python I mean). but as long as it  works :) it should be fine.

Comment: Only works for me when locale path is inside the project. It seems like `LOCALE_PATHS` setting doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 different locale folder in my whole project. But;
I had only 1 locale path. My project structure is;

```
├api_auth
├── project_name_1
│   ├── locale
│   └── settings
├── project_name_2
│   └── locale
│
├── locale 
├── manage.py
└── Dockerfile
```

In settings i have:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), )
```

So i manually add other locale paths like:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_name_1/locale'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_name_2/locale'),
)
```

Hopefully it helps